# opencv DFT source code I know how to get 2N point DFT using N point complex DFT but dont know why it need to another rotating after that process

Tags: opencv, dft

dst is complex DFT results and also is last result when this section code has been done.

```
for( j = 2, wave++; j < n2; j += 2, wave++ )
{
  /* calc odd */
  h2_re = scale2*(dst[j+1] + t);
  h2_im = scale2*(dst[n-j] - dst[j]);

  /* calc even */
  h1_re = scale2*(dst[j] + dst[n-j]);
  h1_im = scale2*(dst[j+1] - t);

  /* rotate  i can not understand this*/
  t = h2_re*wave->re - h2_im*wave->im;
  h2_im = h2_re*wave->im + h2_im*wave->re;
  h2_re = t;
  t = dst[n-j-1];

  dst[j-1] = h1_re + h2_re;
  dst[n-j-1] = h1_re - h2_re;
  dst[j] = h1_im + h2_im;
  dst[n-j] = h2_im - h1_im;
 }
```

why need another rotating where /* rotate */

Answer (score 0):

Because calculating complex FFT firstly on odd and even samples of original sequence, according to [image]

so need to twiddle.